# Rails skip certain columns on Save/Update with different locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

While saving/updating in rails, is it possible to skip/disregard a column if conditions are met in before_save callback ?

Like for example I have a *Products* table  and it has two columns:

- name:string
- price:integer

and a *ProductTranslations* Table

- name_translation:string
- product_id:integer
- locale:string

Is it possible to have a before_save callback like this:

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations
  before_save :check_locale

private
  def check_locale
    if I18n.locale != :en
       # save/update only the price column and don't update name column
       # find ProductTranslation record of product name and update it
    else
       # save/update both the price price column and product name
    end
  end
end
```

What would be the code to disregarding the update name column?

Also, I'm not planning to use a gem like hstore_translations for postgres as I would like to have the code created as a part of the model if possible and maybe for future reference later on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations
  before_update :check_locale

private
  def check_locale
    if I18n.locale != :en
       translations.find_by_local(I18n.locale).update name_translation: name
       write_attribute :name, name_was
       #by owerriding wirte attribute name with name_was(rails cool 
       #thing to get property value that was there before 
       #the new one the one you are sending)
    else
       # save/update both the price price column and product name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is very usefull. Although I'm not sure but I think this will cause an issue if there is a uniqueness validation on name column

EDIT: Nevermind I just tested it and it saved